# Expectation of Integral of Stationnary Process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expected-value, poisson-process

Let $(X(t))_{t \geq 0}$ be a Poisson process, $Z$ a Bernoulli random variable, independent of $X(t)$.

We define $$Y(t)=Z(-1)^{X(t)}$$

It is clear that $Y(t)$ is sationary.

Now we define
$$S(t)=\int_{0}^{t}{Y(v)dv}$$
**Q :** Calculate $E(S(t))$ and $Var(S(t))$

**My attempt :**
$$\begin{align*}
E[S(t)]&=E[\int_{0}^{t}{Y(v)dv}]\\
&=E\Bigg[\int_{0}^{t}{Z(-1)^{X(v)}dv}\Bigg]\\
&=E\Bigg[Z\int_{0}^{t}{(-1)^{X(v)}dv}\Bigg]\\
\end{align*}$$
Here, I defined an operator :
$$T : (\Omega,\mathcal F, \mathbb P) \longrightarrow \mathbb R$$
$$\hspace{5.5cm} W(t) \longrightarrow T(W(t)) = \int_{0}^{t}{W(v)dv}$$

I would then define
$$f :  (\Omega,\mathcal F, \mathbb P) \longrightarrow (\Omega,\mathcal F, \mathbb P) $$
$$ X(t) \longrightarrow f(X(t))=(-1)^{X(t)}$$

Then I would have
$$E[S(t)]= E\Bigg[Z\int_{0}^{t}{(-1)^{X(v)}dv}\Bigg]=E\Big[Z[T(f(X))]\Big]$$

Now I know that if we have two independent r.v's $X$ and $Y$ then for any measurable functions $\varphi$ and $\psi$, the new random variables $\varphi(X)$,$\psi(Y)$ are independent.

The same is applied on $Z$ and $f(X)$. Now the problem lies with the operator $T$. In case there is an independance, it will result that
$$ E\Big[Z[T(f(X))]\Big]=E[Z]\times E[T(f(X))]=0$$

I am not sure how to proceed. This was just an intuitive idea.

Comment: first you write that $t\in\mathbb{N}$, but then you integrate over $t$. Am I missing something here? should it be a sum?

Comment: @Simon it was a mistake, fixed !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $Z$ and $(-1)^{X(t)}$ are independent, therefore the expectation of the product just splits into two.
- $E[\cdot]$ is a linear operation, so you can pull it into the integral.
- Then explicitly use the poisson distribution $P(X(t)=k)=\frac{(t\lambda)^ke^{-t\lambda}}{k!}$

The whole calculation:
\begin{align}
E\left[\int_0^t Z (-1)^{X(v)}\,dv\right]
&= \underbrace{E[Z]}_{=\frac{1}{2}}\cdot \int_0^t E\left[(-1)^{X(v)}\right]\,dv \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{(v\lambda)^ke^{-v\lambda}}{k!}\,dv \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{(v\lambda)^k}{k!}\right)e^{-v\lambda}\,dv \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t e^{-2v\lambda}\,dv \\
&= \frac{1}{4\lambda}\left(1-e^{-2\lambda t}\right)
\end{align}

please check it before using^^